# Simple selects takes so much time to execute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, execution

I have a complex select with JOIN and UNION and it takes long time so I decided to test it in a simple select but this select still takes time to execute. I have saved the execution plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1Jul-VYb)

The code is only

```
SELECT pchrgqty,pchrgup,pcchrgamt  FROM 
hdocord
WHERE acctno = '2014-000136557'
```

But it takes 1 minute and 11 seconds to execute

> How to make this faster?
>   Why is it is very slow?

Comment: It's scanning the whole table. Create an index on `acctno` so it can seek. (Also, consider informing the designer of this table that SQL Server supports up to 128 characters in names, so there's no excuse for unreadable names like those, unless you have to be compatible with a legacy system of some kind.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert i have no access on the database. I want to ask how to add the index for `acctno`? so that i can try to add it. You can provide it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the lacking index just running this SQL statement :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_hdocord_acctno ON hdocord
(
    acctno ASC
)
ON [PRIMARY]
```

It will fail if they haven't given you enough permissions.